# Raphaëljs Select Paper

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to reference a canvas element created by Raphaël.js. The issue is, that, the way I use it, Raphaël.js will create a new canvas that covers the old one. Using jQuery selectors I can retrieve only the DOM node, which doesn't allow me to draw on the canvas.

Example code:

```
<div id='canvas_container' class='canvas_container'></div>
```

```js
function x() {
  var panel = Raphael("canvas_container");
}

function y() {
  Raphael("canvas_container"); // will create new canvas
  $("#canvas_container"); // doesn't allow me to draw on the canvas
}

x();
y();
```

Comment: You should be able to reference the raphael canvas using the 'panel' variable when in function x, right? In function y, you've created a raphael canvas but haven't assigned it to a variable, so you won't be able to reference it again.

Comment: how you are trying to draw? more code please...maybe jsfiddle

Comment: @xiaodili "you've created a raphael canvas but haven't assigned it to a variable".
I am not trying to create a new canvas, I am trying to reference and existing one, the reference will be used in event handling ".on('click',functino(){})'

Answer (score 0):

Raphael currently only exposes functionality to create new Paper as a child of the node with the id you provide, not retrieve a Paper from a DOM node. In the example code you create two separate Papers. In order to create only one and reuse it, you need to keep the reference to the original Paper. One possibility to achieve this would be:

```js
(function() {
  var paper;
  function x() {
    paper = Raphael("canvas_container");
  }
  function y() {
    var c = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
  }
  x();
  y();
})();
```